# Why does this java code not work on linux

Tags: java, linux, cross-platform

OVERVIEW
I am a beginning programmer working on my first videogame, a 2D RTS. I store my sprite images in a folder called "Assets". They are loaded by getting the working directory of the jar then searching for that + "/Assets/myImage.png". This all works good and well on my own computer and others ive given it to- except one. this indevidual is the only non-windows tester and he runs Geltoo linux. for some reason the ImageIO is throwing an error that it was unable to load the input image. At first maybe i thought i was giving the wrong directory (/ vs \ or the like) but im not sure anymore. The code is as follows

-units possess a file Array "SpriteIcon[]" which stores 8 sprites, one for each of the 8 directions. note the unit loads these files using the Main class's assitance (provided relevant methods). Then it runs the middle code that uses ImageIO to read the file and return the image stored in it. this is the part that throws an error.

```
    //unit loading a sprite. spriteIcon is a file.
        this.spriteIcon[i] = new File(Main.getDir() + Main.assets + "TruckSprite.png");

// Code to load the image from the File

            BufferedImage img = null;
            try {
                 //this.setSprite returns a File (loaded by the above code)
                img = ImageIO.read(this.setSprite(pf.direction));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return img;
        }

         /* MAIN CLASS */
        public staic String assets = "Assets+ + File.Separator;

        public static String getDir(){
            String output = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator;
            return output;
    }
```

Comment: + "/Assets/myImage.png"  - you already have used "File.separator".  Use it in place of "/" in your paths.